# My testbench has errors and can't compile this character ( ’ )

Tags: verilog, test-bench

**I want to calculate with it**, but if you think you can write a better testbench for me, please help.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps


  module testbenchDR();
  reg Clk , r , c , i , l ;
  wire  [15:0] dout1 ;
  wire [15:0] bus;
   DR   U0 ( clk, r , c , i , l , dout1 , bus ) ; 
  initial   begin
  clk   =    0 ;
  forever  begin
  clk  =  ~ clk;                                                                                                                                                              
  #20;
  end
  end

  initial    begin
  { r  ,c , i ,  l }   =   4’b0100   ;  /* bus    =  16 ‘ h0f0f;  #200;*/
  { r  ,c , i ,  l }   =   4’b0001   ;   #200;
  { r  ,c , i ,  l }   =   4’b0010  ;   #200;
  { r  ,c , i ,  l }   =   4’b0011      ;   #200;
  { r  ,c , i ,  l }   =   4’b1000  ;   #200;
  { r  ,c , i ,  l }   =   4’b0110      ;   #200;
   end
  endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's strange.  Visually, your apostrophe looks odd to me.  However, when I copy and paste your code into my editor, it looks good.  Just try copy and pasting this code:

```
initial begin
      { r  ,c , i ,  l }   =   4'b0100;
      { r  ,c , i ,  l }   =   4'b0001;   #200;
      { r  ,c , i ,  l }   =   4'b0010;   #200;
      { r  ,c , i ,  l }   =   4'b0011;   #200;
      { r  ,c , i ,  l }   =   4'b1000;   #200;
      { r  ,c , i ,  l }   =   4'b0110;   #200;
end
```

---

On a side note, I got a compile error.  Change:

```
  reg Clk , r , c , i , l ;
```

to (lower-case `clk`):

```
  reg clk , r , c , i , l ;
```

---

Here is your code running on [edaplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/3yJf), without the `DR` module (since you didn't post that code).